# Plot of time series with gray areas in intervals that go beyond the mean

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I would like to plot a time series with shaded gray areas in the intervals that go above the mean. Any ideas on how to do so? or where to start looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without information, it is hard to answer, but here is a potential outcome using `ggplot`:

[image]

```
data = data.frame(x = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-03-31"), as.POSIXct("2017-04-01"), by = "1 hour"),
              y = rnorm(25, 10, 3))

mean.y = mean(data$y)

ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(data = subset(data, y > mean.y), aes(ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, xmin = x - 30*60, xmax = x + 30*60), fill = "grey") +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean.y, color = "red")
```